# Slow first request after period of inactivity

Tags: python, performance, flask, server

I'm using a hetzner server and a flask application

And my project is a dialog between servers

---

Server A : website -> requesting some datas with json (GET METHOD);
Server B : server -> send the datas to server A

---

Usually each requests takes around **300 ms** but after period of inactivity my request takes like **20000ms**, no errors shown, it's just slow.

I thought first it was my code but server B timer didn't change even when it's a slow request so it's only due to the dialog.

Does someone know what to do to fix this issue ?

My first idea is to ping this server at a short interval to break the inactivity but it looks dirty.

Thank you in advance for your help people

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I was using gunicorn and my `.Service` file was like:

```
ExecStart=/var/www/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myApp.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

but it should be like:

```
ExecStart=/var/www/venv/bin/gunicorn --timeout 120 --workers 3 --bind unix:myApp.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

You need to setup a timeout. I don’t know why, though.